# Access stored travel time in SUMO from Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using Omnet++ 5.3, veins 4.7.1 and Sumo 0.32.0. I have given values to a lane parameter called "stored travel time" present in SUMO using an additional weight file. I would like to know if there's a way to access this value from Omnet++. If I use the function getCurrentTravelTime I get the old values and not the ones I have specifically provided. Any help to achieve the task is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give step by step instructions, such as what to put in which file? This would make it easier to reproduce the behavior on another machine and, then, diagnose the problem

Comment: [link](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/Lane-_or_Edge-based_Traffic_Measures.html#edge-based_network_states) A file of the format given in the link is created with values given for edge id and travel time alone. This file is added by giving the line `<weight-files value="weight.add.xml"/>` to the sumo.cfg file and `<copy file="weight.add.xml" />` to the launchd file.